# Would we want this question migrated here from Programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154118/34339) was closed as off-topic on Programmers, but looks like it might be a fit here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly that was brought to my attention and I rejected it. It's very ranty with lots of irrelevant details making it a poor question.

I'd be okay with a similar, properly asked question on this site, but not that question in it's current form.

Comment: Yes, I was going to say the same thing -- I just checked the Teachers' Lounge chat transcript for the original question to us from Programmers.SE mods a few days back.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less ranty, remove unnecessary details to make it more widely applicable, and generally clean it up a bit. It looks to me like a better fit now.

Comment: @Jim thanks for the effort, but it appears [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-improve-a-resume-to-avoid-looking-like-a-job-hopper) is a more focused, better question along the same line. [jcmeloni also agrees we shouldn't move it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5143671#5143671). Sorry to have sent you on an edit goose chase